# Vagrant "domain forwarding"

Tags: networking, subdomain, vagrant

Currently, I've got used to creating development domains like:  **projecttowork.dev**.

Now I have a project, where I have to use subdomains as well, so like: **module1.project.dev**

I would like to start using Vagrant, because it looks awesome and I work together with some other people, and it would be great to have the same server everywhere.

In Vagrant, of course I can forward a port, like :8000 and get the server on virtual machine, but I can not figure out, how to "forward" a domain.

I tried different ways, but without any success.

Some details:

- OS: Windows 8
- Vagrant box: basic Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Webserver on client: Nginx
- Webserver on host: Apache (if needed)

How could I redirect this development domain to the virtual server?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I'm coming across the same problem. The solutions below don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 6):

-My settings in Vagrant file for **network** is:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.20.20" #choose you own
```

-In the **host** machine in **/etc/hosts** (linux) **Windows/system32/driv.../hosts** (windows)

```
192.168.20.20 domain.tld
```

-On the **box** check firewall (iptables - if the box is linux).

- either deactivate your firewall on the box(I did this)  or setup it to allow access from the host machine. (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-examples.html)

-In the **box** set **virtualhost** for this domain (just an example):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.tld

  DocumentRoot "/path"
  RewriteEngine On

  <Directory "/path">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you add some detail to your answer, especially what you mean about "Check iptables settings".

Comment: Added one more sentence to iptables, hope its better now ;)

Comment: Worth noting, the `hosts` file is at `/etc/hosts` on *nix machines – on Windows 8 it is probably located at `\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: This plugin can automate `hosts` updates: https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater

Answer (score 0):

Did you use etc/hosts file before to point dev domains to your dev machines IP? Same way, just add 1 row per subdomain to point them to you vagrant box IP, for example:

module1.project.dev 192.168.1.2
module2.project.dev 192.168.1.2
...

Comment: sorry for the late reply, of course, I use the hosts file for every subdomain. Unfortunately, it is still unreachable.